# Trying to minimize a function over the integers

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I am trying to evaluate the following expression.

```
Minimize[
  {Abs[Log[10, 1 - 0.9] - (11 Log[10, 1 - 0.68^x] + 9 Log[10, 1 - 0.74^y])], 
   x >= 0, y >= 0, x <= 20, y <= 20}, 
  {x, y}, Integers]
```

I want the values of x and y that minimize the above function, but I get the following error:

> The function value Indeterminate is not a number at {x,y} = {19.265, 0.0547502}

When I evaluate without the `Integers` specification, I get the answer

> `{1.55673*10^-10, {x -> 15.8488, y -> 4.97415}}`

I need x and y to be integers in my formulation. Could someone please guide me in the correct direction?

I do not have a strong math background, so I would really appreciate the explanation in layman's terms.

Comment: Try again but with exact values in place of the decimal values: i.e. replace `0.68` with `(68/100)` and so on.

Comment: It works! Thanks!! Any idea why this is a problem?

Comment: Not exactly, other than that *Mathematica* has a lot of symbolic computing machinery built into it that it can sometimes use to solve problems symbolically, but when inexact numbers are used in the expressions, it defaults to numerical routines, which can be a little fiddly.

Comment: Well, I wish I had asked this question 5 days ago when I first encountered the problem :), thanks again!